# Text not appearing in FlashDevelop project. But not throwing any errors either

Tags: actionscript-3

**UPDATE**

I found something that works!  I'll post this as *an* answer when the timer is up.  In the meantime, I'll accept an answer that can explain why my solution works:

I changed this line

```
private var myAtariFormat:TextFormat = new TextFormat(myFatPixels.fontName,25,0x00ffff);
```

to this:

```
private var myAtariFormat:TextFormat = new TextFormat("fatPixel",25,0x00ffff);
```

and included the `embedAsCFF = "false"`.

and it worked. I'm not sure I see why. Is this obvious to anyone that cares to explain it?  Is it because "`Class`" doesn't have a property "`fontName`"? and we are calling my font a `Class` instead of a `Font`?

---

### Original Post

This is my first time using FlashDevelop.  I have buttons in a menu and a scoreboard.  These all have a text field in them.  In Adobe Animate, all worked fine, but in FlashDevelop, I understand I need to embed the fonts using strictly AS3 code, as there is no GUI library to drop them into.

I found this [snippet](http://snipplr.com/view/40079/embed-truetype-font-in-flashdevelop-flex-4/) but it only confirms (I think) that I've done it correctly, which obviously, I have not.

So here is my current permutation that does not throw any errors, and the game loads and runs fine (but there is no text anywhere) and the buttons work, but there is not text anywhere:

```
public class Main extends Sprite 
{

// ********** EMBEDDED ASSESTS **       
    [Embed(source = "/../lib/FATPIXEL.TTF", fontName = "fatPixel")] public static var myFatPixels:Class;
```

and then while creating a menu button:

```
// ********* BUTTONS **********
    private var button1:RoundButton= new RoundButton(60,30,gameReset,0xff386c,0x0,"1 Player");
```

Those are both in my main doc class. 
The following includes the constructor in my button class as well as the property declaration part inside the package:

```
    [Embed(source = "/../lib/AtariSmall.ttf", fontName = "smallAtari")] public var myAtariFont:Class;       
    public var tF:TextField = new TextField();
    private var myAtariFormat:TextFormat = new TextFormat(myFatPixels.fontName,25,0x00ffff);        

    var b:Sprite = new Sprite;
    var txt:String = new String();

    public function RoundButton(w:Number,h:Number,f:Function,colorA:uint,colorB:uint = 0x555599,text:String="button",dat2:Boolean = false):void {
        addChild(tF);
        tF.text = text;
        tF.embedFonts = true;
        tF.setTextFormat(myAtariFormat);
        tF.defaultTextFormat = myAtariFormat;
    }
```

Oh, and my `.ttf` files are here:

[image]

Can anyone see what is causing my problem?  In Adobe Animate embedding was made simpler by having that option in a drop-down menu and having GUI access to the library.  The syntax was notably different in that I was able to use the Font class whereas all sources I've found online show me to use the Class class?  Here's what I mean:

**Adobe Animate**

```
var myFatPixels:Font = new FatPixels();
```

**FlashDevelop**

```
var myFatPixels:Class;
```

I think if I understood better the difference between these two lines of code I could figure out what I'm doing wrong.

So, I made a simple script to just at least try to get some text to show up.  It works, but the font look like Times New Roman or some other system font, and not the font that it is supposed to look like.  Here's my code that does this:

```
package
{
    import flash.display.Shape;
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.text.*;

    /**
     * ...
     * @author Neal Davis
     */

    public class Main extends Sprite 
    {
        [Embed(source = "../lib/FATPIXEL.TTF", fontName = "fatPixel")] public static var myFatPixels:Class;
        private var tF:TextField = new TextField();
        private var myFont:Font = new myFatPixels();
        private var myAtariFormat:TextFormat = new TextFormat(myFatPixels.fontName,25,0xB6A4E3);    


        public function Main() 
        {
            removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
            trace("hello world");
            var b:Sprite = new Sprite();
            addChild(b);
            b.addChild(tF);
            tF.defaultTextFormat = myAtariFormat;
            tF.text = "button";
            tF.setTextFormat(myAtariFormat);
        }

    }

}
```

The result being

[image: TimeNewRomanFont]

but it should look more like

[image: fatPixelFont]

Comment: Aaaargh, @NealDavis, You will solve this issue by yourself :)
Kind regards.
Nicolas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed this line

```
private var myAtariFormat:TextFormat = new TextFormat(myFatPixels.fontName,25,0x00ffff);
```

to this:

```
private var myAtariFormat:TextFormat = new TextFormat("fatPixel",25,0x00ffff);
```

and included the `embedAsCFF = "false".`

I *think* it is because we can only embed an element of type `Class` (not `Font`) and `Class` doesn't have a property of `fontName`.  So getting `myFatPixel.fontName` doesn't return anything? Maybe? I mean it seems like it should since we declare a `fontName` value in the embed line, but at any rate, passing the literal String of the name ("fatPixel") did the trick.

### Christmas Eve Update

In response to BadFeelingAboutThis' idea that it may be an order of operations issue, I did the following:

```
    public function RoundButton(w:Number,h:Number,f:Function,colorA:uint,colorB:uint = 0x555599,text:String="button",dat2:Boolean = false):void {

        [Embed(source = "/../lib/FATPIXEL.ttf", fontName = "fatPixel", embedAsCFF = "false")] 
        var myFatPixels:Class;
        myAtariFormat = new TextFormat(myFatPixels.fontName,25,0x00ffff);
```

And the buttons appear with no text.  Again, when I switch `myFatPixels.fontName` to simply `"fatPixel"` all is well.  So it didn't appear to be an order of operations issue in this case, unless I'm missing your point?

Comment: Most likely, this works (or rather the original doesn't work) because of order of operations.  Your class is initialized (all the functions and vars created), then the classes it references are created (if not already).  Since you're trying to reference your embedded class in your `Main` classes signature (eg not inside a function), that code gets run when you class is being initialized (but the embedded class not been initialized yet).    If you moved your assignment of the `myAtariFormat` var from the signature/var declaration into the construction function, it would likely work.

Comment: Finding documentation about the class level order of execution is difficult though so I'm just guessing.  At any rate, it's not a good idea to assign anything other than primitive values to class scoped vars as there's no promise they'll be available at that time.

Comment: Ah. I think I see what you are saying. I will take a swing at it tonight or after the holiday and let you know.

Comment: @BadFeelingAboutThis please see my update in this answer above.  Thanks.